# People picker postback bug in 2007

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have a page with several people pickers and I've noticed that if my form does more than one postback (i.e. if the user enters an incorrect person in the people picker) my form breaks I lose elements of the form (drop down values for instance) I've seen this discussed here.

https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/devwiki/articles/Pages/Workaround-for-People-Picker-Post-back-Bug-in-ASPX-pages-in-SharePoint-2010.aspx

and i think i'm experiencing the same...does anyone have a workaround for this?

S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the fix...best way to fix is to change the viewstate on the item that's losing its value to false. Worked for me.

S